# Stuttering playback on large MP4 with Vitamio

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating an app that has a function that plays user selected video's. Nothing fancy, just playback of video's on the device itself without any advanced settings. Since MediaPlayer has issues with some video types I use Vitamio. It works great on smaller compressed video's but when I select a mp4 video that I've recorded with my phone itself it stutters, both audio and video. I tried changing video quality of the  Vitamio Media Player, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I'm quite stuck in finding a solution, anyone who has any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please sure the video you recorded is ok, you can playback the video use [VPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.abitno.vplayer.t&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIm1lLmFiaXRuby52cGxheWVyLnQiXQ..). or pull the video to your computer playback it.
2. if first ok ,you can try use Vitamio hardware decoder playback it.

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried VPlayer and it also stutters on VPlayer. If I use MX Player it plays like a charm, so I guess it's an issue with the library. Since FFMpeg requires NDK experience and I don't have any I guess I have to skip this functionality.

Comment: @RaymondP, can you send the video to me (e.g. upload google driver or dropbox), i'll download it